# Sound not playing with AVAudioPlayer in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Pretty new to Objective-C and programming in Xcode and I can't quite understand why my sound is not playing. I followed this tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mbCkIVF1-0) but for some reason I cannot get my sounds to play in the iOS Simulator. I am using a storyboard layout rather than a nib file so maybe that could be the problem ? I know how to connect my buttons to the storyboards that I have so I'm pretty confused and this problem is driving me crazy. Any help is greatly appreciated, if my code is wrong please point me in the right direction, the problem might be something trivial, either way any help would be great! Thanks again

SFViewController.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>


@interface SFViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

}
-(IBAction)playSound1;
-(IBAction)playSound2;
-(IBAction)playSound3;

@end
```

SFViewController.h

```
#import "SFViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>


@implementation SFViewController



-(IBAction)playSound1 {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeriouslyFunnySound1" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]error:NULL];

    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

-(IBAction)playSound2 {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeriouslyFunnySound2" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]error:NULL];

    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

-(IBAction)playSound3 {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeriouslyFunnySound3" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]error:NULL];

    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: first try isolating your problem: is your code inside the IBAction methods actually being called (ie put log statements inside and see if they get called).. do they?

Answer (score 9):

Your "theAudio" variable is getting lost when going out of scope, so the player stops. Keep the variable as a member of your class:

```
@implementation SFViewController
{
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio;
}

-(IBAction)playSound1 {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeriouslyFunnySound1" ofType:@"wav"];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]error:NULL];

    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting such a concise answer. I encountered this very problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing `NULL` to your `AVAudioPlayer` inits? Pass in a nil pointer to an `NSError` and ensure the error is still nil after initing. My best guess is that there is some error and `theAudio` is actually nil.

Comment: as I said I am new to Xcode and I did that because it is what the tutorial told me to do

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that your IBAction methods are actually being called (put an NSLog statement inside those methods and see if they get called.. if they're not.. I'm sure you can figure it out on your own)

second: Create an NSError object and pass in it's address to see the nature of your problem like so:

```
 NSError *err= nil
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeriouslyFunnySound1" 
                                                  ofType:@"wav"];
 AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = 
      [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                                             error:err];
 if (!theAudio) {
     NSLog(@"failed playing SeriouslyFunnySound1, error: %@", error);
 }

 theAudio.delegate = self;
 [theAudio play];
```

the contents of err should tell you what to do next

Comment: Since the OP is new, I suggest you update this answer with code to check if `theAudio` is `nil` and logging the error.

Answer (score 0):

Encountering the same issue. Here is the answer in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var soundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    @IBAction func newPomodoButtonTaped(sender: UIButton) {
       let soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("click_done", ofType: "wav")!
      do {
            soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: soundPath)!)
            soundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            soundPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
            soundPlayer.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```